# Magento 2 :Display attribute option values

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes

I have created a field in **system->confi**g to save an attribute code which is already created.(For eg:color)

Based on that value, I need to get all the option values of that attribute.(ie ,In my admin form drop down, I need to display its option values as red,blue,green).

How it is possible ? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Add to the constructor in your class an instance of `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` like this:

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ...
}
```

then you can use that in your class

```
$attribute_code_here = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/template_hints', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code_here);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Comment: @V.P, If my answer solve your issue then mark as accepted. So other user take benefits from this.

Comment: I also want to show product attribute label in custom grid instead of attribute value. Currently it showing attribute option value. please suggest

Comment: I want to display attribute options dropdown in admin form and grid, please help me